# Is "Are you back" in meaning of "Did you come back" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I've got a message from a friend which is an English native speaker from Africa and he he wrote me "**Are you back**?" in meaning of "**Did you come back**?" (to the country that he is in). This is the first time that I came across such usage and I would like to ask if it is correct usage in English or just slang or something like that?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked "back" on an online dictionary? Especially, the adjective entry. I am sure you have heard "I'll be right back". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/back

Comment: Honestly, no. I didn't even think about such option. Interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you back? is current BrE and quite appropriate to ask of a colleague who has been away and might or might not have returned.

Did you come back? is a grammatically correct question but for different circumstances, such as if you had said "I just went to the most wonderful place on Earth".